# API Manager 4.1.0 Dynamic value for accessControlAllowOrigins

Tags: cors, wso2, apim

Is it possible to use the params.yml file to define different accessControlAllowOrigins for environments as well as endpoints?
I want to define this for apis and api-products.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the moment CORs configs are not supported in the params.yaml. You can find the supported list here - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/advanced-topics/configuring-environment-specific-parameters/#defining-the-parameters-file-for-an-api

You can define backend service endpoints in the params.yaml